# SP Designer Workflows doesn't work

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a big problem to start the SPD Workflow as well as in 2010 version as in 2013.
I need to create the workflow for SP 2010 list and downloaded the SP Designer 2010. I am the beginner in this area and study how to work with it by videos and forums in internet. To assure that everything is right, I used the instruction http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-HA101859249.aspx . But when I press on buttom to create the workflow nothing happen, it doesn't do anything like I don't press, just updating the page.

I decided to check if I do something wrong on another site which is already moved to 2013 version (full control rights as well). I downloaded the SP Designer 2013 and here the working window appeared but it requareds to instal Visio Pro [image] [image]
(according to the description http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/10/22/introducing-the-new-visual-designer.aspx it should be Pro), I have only standart.

So I have two questions:
1) why SDP workflow 2010 doesn't work?
2) How can I disable the Visual Designer in SPD 2013?

Thank you in advance for help!

Pic for my comment to answer 1 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 2013, follow this TechNet update to fix the viso issue!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752031

---

for 2010 sounds like your in the wrong place, as make sure your SPD 2010 is the same version as your OS (32bit or 64bit)

follow this simple guide:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125120/Step-by-Step-Guide-in-Developing-your-own-Workflow

for SPD 2013 guide follow:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for help! Now SPD 2013 works the appropriate way and the guide which you recomended are very good! But problem with SPD 2010 still haven't solved. I cheked the vesion, it is correct. The same with place it should be correct, because I do the same in SP 2013  by SPD 2013 and it works.I tried to change existing workflows, it doesn't work too (pic with mistake on the question fild). In addition I tried to make a workflow on site SP 2010 by SPD 2013, it see the site but the story fully the same like with SPD 2010. What else can be the problem?

Comment: I found the solution for problem SPD 2010. It is here http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/85904.aspx Ali, one more time thank you very much gor help with solving the problem with SPD 2013

Comment: no problem happy to help!, didnt know your using office 365 for 2010 ;)