# Where is the mistake in workflow?

Tags: workflow, date-time

I have the following issue. To make the automatization of the process I need to fix the date & time for each process step. First I used the calculated column but it didn't work. I found suggestion how to make it [SharePoint Designer Workflow, set field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65614/sharepoint-designer-workflow-set-field) but didn't understand how to apply it and created the question: [How to fix [today] and [now] in a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109759/how-to-fix-today-and-now-in-the-sharepoint-2010-list/109781#109781).

Using this information as well as recommended guides from answer on this question [SP Designer Workflows doesn't work](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109931/sp-designer-workflows-doesnt-work)
and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQYldayTe1M

I created the workflow for process: I need that when a person chooses "Yes" in the Status column that in column "Date &  Time" appears current date and time and that this time would not be changed if somebody  updates the information in the string. [image]

But it doesn't work.

During the publishing the next mistake appeared

[image]

Additional info about mistake:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation failed with error System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The caller does not have the necessary permissions required for this operation. Permissions granted: None. Required permissions: WriteScope. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 955a3a11-0d8c-4875-9578-e29dc77813cb. NodeId: 011D-DB3-PFE03. Scope: /SPODScope/default/53737d38-1b0c-454f-bcb8-84f703c0a710. Client ActivityId : 7763a89c-385b-1025-e86c-040129c55387. ---> System.Net.WebExcept

but than it was published.

Is the problem in the mistake or in my code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known issue with Workflow Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193462(v=azure.10).aspx):

### If the permissions of a workflow scope are set to BUILTIN\Administrators, Client Applications must run using elevated permissions

If the permissions of a workflow scope are set to `BUILTIN\Administrators`, which is the default setting, an exception similar to the following is thrown if the client application is not run using elevated permissions.

This is because Windows doesn’t grant the current user the Admin token unless the user is running in an elevated process, regardless of whether that user belongs to the Administrators group.

To resolve this issue, there are two choices.

- Run the client application using elevated permissions.
- Update the [WorkflowAdminGroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.workflow.client.security.windowssecurityconfiguration.workflowadmingroupname(v=azure.10).aspx) of the scope to another
  non-Administor group to which the user belongs, such as
  `BUILTIN\Users`. One way to do this is to run the following PowerShell
  script.

PowerShell Script

```
$sec = New-Object Microsoft.Workflow.Client.Security.WindowsSecurityConfiguration("All Users")
$sec.WorkflowAdminGroupName = "Users"
```